# Flutter Responsive Aspect Ratio With MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, media-queries, aspect-ratio

I am using a video player plugin in flutter [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player). The setup works well, wrt the plugin functionalities. I am required to setup an `aspect ratio` for the plugin to size itself. I have done this in code like below (for my device):

```
return Scaffold(
  body: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 4.5/3,
    // aspectRatio: width / height * 0.35,
    child: BetterPlayer(
      key: _playerKey,
      controller: _controller,
    ),
  )
);
```

It works great on my device but on smaller screens (and possibly larger form factors), it doesn't scale properly. On smaller devices, the video player doesn't take up the full device width. Had earlier tried using `popular aspect ratios like 3/2, 4/3` etc to no avail as the height now became an issue.

I tried one more option, which is to use `media query` to calculate the aspect ratio using a height factor favorable to me such as `aspectRatio: width / height * 0.35,` but I keep getting this error:

```
The method '/' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: /(null)
```

This occurs when I'm trying to this arithmetic operation : `width / height * 0.35`. Any ideas how to build the aspect ratio using MQs for adaptive user interfaces? Thanks

Full Code:

```
class AkilahVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _AkilahVideoPlayerState createState() => _AkilahVideoPlayerState();
}

class _AkilahVideoPlayerState extends State<AkilahVideoPlayer> {

BetterPlayerDataSource _dataSource;
BetterPlayerController _controller;

final _playerKey = GlobalKey();
var height, width;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  print('ar in initState() of screen\t${width ~/ height * 0.35}');
  // print('ar in initState() of screen\t${width~/height * 0.35}');

  _dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
      sampleVideoOne,
      notificationConfiguration: BetterPlayerNotificationConfiguration(
        showNotification: true,
        title: 'Big Buck Bunny',
        // imageUrl: 'assets/big_buck_bunny.jpg',
        author: 'Akilah',
      )
   );

   _controller = BetterPlayerController(
      BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        aspectRatio: 4.5/3,
        // aspectRatio: width / height * 0.35,
        // aspectRatio: 4/3,
        autoPlay: false,
        showPlaceholderUntilPlay: true,
        controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
            enableMute: true,
            enableOverflowMenu: true,
            overflowMenuIcon: const IconData(0xe146, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons',),
           showControlsOnInitialize: false,
           playerTheme: BetterPlayerTheme.material,
           enableProgressText: true
        ),
        placeholder: Image.asset('assets/big_buck_bunny.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
    ),
       betterPlayerDataSource: _dataSource
    );

   _controller.enablePictureInPicture(_playerKey);
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
   height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  // print('ar in build() of screen\t${width / height * 0.35}');

  return Scaffold(
    body: AspectRatio(
      // aspectRatio: 4.5/3,
      aspectRatio: width / height * 0.35,
      child: BetterPlayer(
        key: _playerKey,
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    )
   );
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `MediaQuery` properly. Here you can use it like this:

```dart
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

This will give you proper width and height.

Comment: I have that in my build method, only showed the scaffold part. Will edit the question, thanks

Comment: Well, if you are using it then it doesn't make sense that both of those values are null. The error is because they are null.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Check the question again

Comment: I have solved this issue by removing the surrounding AspectRatio widget enclosing the player plugin and just setting aspect ratio in controller.